# commenting each line of a copy loop with what the line does

Tags: assembly, x86, masm

I need help commenting this code.

My assignment stated I need to "write what each line does as a comment into the code".

I am not sure I commented them correctly

```
    .386
    .model flat

    .data
    quote byte "Machines do feel",0   ; message output 
    message byte SIZEOF quote DUP(0),0    

    .code
start proc              ; start of the procedure
mov esi, 0              ; value of esi is zero
mov ecx, SIZEOF quote   ; stores size of the text in ecx
    LP:

mov al, quote[esi]
mov message[esi],al
inc esi               ; increment esi's value
loop LP               ; loop


ret 
    start endp
    end start
```

Comment: You are using the comments incorrectly. They are not to inform readers what an instruction does — that can be found from the assembler  manual. They should be used to give **added value** to the code. For example `inc esi ; next array element`.

Comment: Are you supposed to write normal comments, like you would for a real program written in asm?  (Where you can assume that the reader knows what simple instructions like `inc` do, and the only value in a comment is *why* the code is doing them.)  Or are you supposed to demonstrate that you understand how each instruction changes the architectural state by describing that (and the assignment wants you to put that in a comment.)  The 2nd kind of comment is basically useless, because `inc esi` already tells you *what* it does, but not that it's the loop counter.

Comment: I am knew to coding so this is the first assignment that I have and instructions stated to write what each line does as a comment into the code

Comment: @PeterCordes I should demonstrate that I understand what they do and I am having some troubles as it is my very first assignment

Comment: A relevant "what it does" comment for the `loop` line would be `dec ecx / jnz LP` ([How exactly does the x86 LOOP instruction work?](//stackoverflow.com/q/46881279)), or English text saying that.  Obviously just repeating the instruction mnemonic is completely useless.  Again, you wouldn't comment this way normally, the assignment is asking you to use comments as a way to fill in an answer, not as useful comments.  e.g. `esi += 1` is already obvious to anyone reading `inc esi`.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because stackoverflow is not a proof-your-homework service.

Answer (score 1):

I don't see any reason why the rules of comments are significantly different just because assembly lanuage. "Comment the why." But because registers have bad names, we have to comment what they are used for, like any other case where we can't use a good name.

```
    .386
    .model flat

    .data
    quote byte "Machines do feel",0   ; message output 
    message byte SIZEOF quote DUP(0),0    

    .code
start proc
mov esi, 0             ; esi = offset counter
mov ecx, SIZEOF quote  ; ecx = loop counter
    LP:

mov al, quote[esi]     ; Copy bytes from quote to message
mov message[esi],al
inc esi
loop LP


ret 
    start endp
    end start
```

This indentation isn't idiomatic, but it's consistent so I'm not going to poke at it.

But why did you call this start like it's your entry point? This doesn't make sense as an entry point.

Comment: I removed the `[comments]` tag on this question, because the OP clarified their assignment wants them to use the comment field to describe *what* the line does.  So it's not a question about how to comment asm, it's apparently just about transliterating asm to pseudocode or English.  (But yes, your answer is correct.)

Comment: @PeterCordes: I now ponder closing question as off topic.

Comment: I was thinking "unclear what you're asking" because there's not much of a real question, but I think I'm just going to give up on this one.  The OP can look up instructions in https://www.felixcloutier.com/x86/index.html, and other directives in the MASM manual.

Answer (score 1):

If your assignment says that you need to "write what each line does as a comment into the code"; then you need to write what each line does (and not just what each instruction does).

Assuming that you don't need to comment empty ("whitespace only") lines; there are 11 lines that you haven't commented.

For example (the first few lines only), you probably want something like:

```
    .386        ;Tell assembler that the code is intended for an 80386 CPU (e.g. allow 32-bit instructions)
    .model flat ;Tell assembler to use the "flat" memory model (no use of segments and segment registers)

    .data       ;Tell assembler that subsequent lines are for the ".data" section of the output file
```

Of course (as others have mentioned) you would never do this in normal programming - it's purely to satisfy the requirements of the assignment.